# High output current hex inverter in SMD capsule

Tags: components, inverter

I am trying to find a hex inverter which has as high output current as 74AC04E (50mA) but surface mounted.

I haven't had any luck so far...

Comment: Capsule?        (fifteen chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better luck searching for what your after as a "inverting buffer" or "inverting line driver" or simply a "buffer" as many have an invert option.  They often come with 4,8,16,32 I/Os.

[Texas Instruments](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?&familyId=280&uiTemplateId=SZVI_T&techFamId=null&rootFamilyId=null&sectionId=null&tabId=null&appId=null&viewDeviceCallingPage=null&totalCount=387&showAdditionalParameters=no&parameter=2475604390&lc=3000199&lc=3000214&lc=3000202&lc=2000437&lc=2000438&lc=2000440&lc=2000441&lc=2000444&lc=2000454&lc=2000469&lc=2001498&lc=2000460&lc=2000470&lc=2000564&lc=2001512&compare=yes&download=yes&sort=yes&customize=yes&paramResults=yes&paramCriteria=yes&familyTree=yes&military=no&baSystem=yes&paramTable=no&sortOption=PA_SUB_FAMILY_NAME&sortMode=ASC&searchPaths=1000280&pageId=280&templateId=0&navigationId=0&family=logic&paramTable=no&military=no&&uiTemplateId=SZVI_T&techFamId=null&rootFamilyId=null&sectionId=null&tabId=null&appId=null&viewDeviceCallingPage=null&resetCompare=true#sdp) has a few, I chose them at random though, there are plenty of companies that make such parts.  likely at whatever voltage/current/propagation delay you could want.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a Darlington driver chip with six or more channels. Some come with built in inverters, and some come in versions with inverters and without. These can output up to 500mA per channel, depending on thermal dissipation and the output current for all other channels.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a p channel mosfet.  Pull up the gate to your logic level, say 5 V, and connect a series resistor from your logic source to the gate.  This will invert a logic level of 0 and turn the p-channel mosfet on, and a logic input of 1, will turn the p-channel mosfet off.

So you have inversion, and current is only limited by your choice of mosfet.

Answer (score 0):

The 74AC04E has a rated operating of current of +-24mA. The 50mA is the absolute
maximum rating which you should not be operating at. There is also an absolute maximum
rated current of 100mA into Vcc or GND for the package.

IIRC LVC family form TI has the same +-24mA output currents. TI also has some power logic
devices. Not sure is they have a hex inverter or just a shift register. You could also
try Allegro.

For CMOS devices you can parallel the input and outputs of gates within the same package
to increase the current drive. Do not parallel gates from different packages.